# Página recarrega ao adicionar produto no carrinho - wp - wc

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Estou tentando adicionar um produto no carrinho sem atualizar a página, porém por mais que a opção do wc de usar ajax esteja ativada ela não funciona.

Eu queria saber como posso editar para não atualizar.

Comment: Tente adicionar algo no carrinho com o console do navegar aberto e verifique se não tem nenhum erro.

Comment: O console não traz erro.

Comment: Olha na aba network do navegador se ele realmente executa o ajax quando você click em add no carrinho.

Comment: Aparentemente sim

Comment: Qual o retorno do Ajax?

Comment: Ele não executa, o que ele envia é um post.